# Running a PHP program with YouTube API in OAuth2 mode for more than 1 hour

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, youtube-data-api

I need to run quarterly a PHP program to retrieve the metadata for a friend's YouTube channel which has close to 40,000 videos.

I can only retrieve the data for about 8,000 + or - videos before the authorization token expires.

How can I dynamically acquire and switch to a new token and continue until all videos on the channel have been processed?

If I run the program without the token I get about 20,000 videos' data.

```
$iurl = "accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=" . $client_id 
    . "&response_type=token&redirect_uri=" . $redirect_uri
    . "&scope=" . $scopes;
```

The current request: `header("Location: " . $url);`

Comment: get data with pagination like : first get 100 videos, then 101-200 and so on. Also needs to increase authorization token expire time if possible.

Comment: How can "authorization token expire time" be increased?

Comment: During the OAuth2 process you cant increase the expire time by requesting with pagination. You have to use the refresh token and a refresh request to receive a new access token, that has a new expire time.

Answer (score 1):

If you 're requesting an access token via OAuth2 mode you 'll receive an access token and a refresh token in the response.

A typical response looks like this ...

```
{
  "access_token": "1/fFAGRNJru1FTz70BzhT3Zg",
  "expires_in": 3920,
  "token_type": "Bearer",
  "scope": "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl",
  "refresh_token": "1//xEoDL4iW3cxlI7yDbSRFYNG01kVKM2C-259HOF2aQbI"
}
```

You can calculate the expiration time with the `expires_in` parameter for yourself or you can just request with the access token as you do it already. As you expirienced you 'll get an error response, which says, that the token is expired. Luckily the OAuth2 process gives you the possibility to [refresh your access token](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/auth/server-side-web-apps#offline) with the refresh token.

```
POST /token HTTP/1.1
Host: oauth2.googleapis.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

client_id=your_client_id&
client_secret=your_client_secret&
refresh_token=refresh_token&
grant_type=refresh_token
```

In the response you 'll receive a new access token with a new lifetime. Beware! There are limits in the YouTube / Google API. You can reuse the refresh token from the first access token request and refresh your access token until the refresh token is invalid.

Comment: Thank you.

I only get the following parameters when I manually request a token:

access_token=<162 character token starting with ya29.>&token_type=Bearer&scope=<scope>&expires_in=3599

Comment: Well, you have not said how you request your access token. The OAuth2 process works with a refresh token. However ... without a refresh token you have to request a new access token and then continue with requesting the video data at the point the last access token was invalid.

Comment: This is how the tokens was requested: ***

$iurl = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=" . $client_id . "&response_type=token&redirect_uri=".$redirect_uri."&scope=" . $scopes;

THE ACTUAL REQUEST:

header("Location: " . $url);

Comment: Have you read the current YouTube API OAuth2 documentation? https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/auth/server-side-web-apps#obtainingaccesstokens You should not request an access token via redirect. You should use cURL for the oAuth2 protocoll. There are helpful examples in the documentation.

Comment: Thank you. Am studying it and plan to try what is learned.

Comment: I can now get an Access Token and a Refresh Token. Progress ...

When can I refresh the Access Token token? When an error occurs after it expires (3699 seconds) or any time after  that>

Comment: I 'd suggest, that you use the refresh token, when the access token is expired. The API will send a 401 response `401 Unauthorized` when the access token has expired. If the status code of the response is `401` use the refresh token and request a new access token. Actually you can use the refresh token any time. But that makes no sense at all since the API limits the use of refresh tokens. There 's no unlimited access. It 's better to use the expiration time and act like I described before.

Comment: Thank you VERY MUCH!

You helped  LOT!

Hope others too will learn from what you wrote.